# @Transactional and @EntityListeners together

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, transactional, entitylisteners

I've encountered an interesting issue when writing Spring Boot integration tests for my application. The issue is when trying to call delete on jpa repository, the following exception is thrown:

```
TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call
```

My tests are verifying that certain actions are executed appropriately based on the data in the database. As such, my tests use jpa repository directly to find, save and delete data. Few of my entities also use `@EntityListeners` to perform actions on post commit and in some cases before commit.

There's a thread on stackoverflow suggesting that I should have @Transactional annotation, on class, or method. The problem with that, in my scenario, is that if I add `@Translactional` annotation, the `@EntityListeners` are not triggered for some reason, and because of that my tests fail. So it's sort of chicken and egg problem.

Is there any way to trigger entity listeners with `@Transactional` annotation?

Comment: You mean add `@Transactional` to test class itself? That will unfortunately mess with your setup, unless code under test creates its own nested transactions (I mean, that is a possibility, in the end). I would suggest going with programmatic transaction instead, and verify your saved data via `TransactionSynchronization` framework.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov - Yes, test class or test method. I've added it to the test helper method and it seems to workaround the `TransactionRequiredException`. However, the side effect is that it doesn't trigger entity listeners. I'm already using `TransactionSynchroinzationManager` in my `@EntityListeners` class (if that's what you are suggesting) - but afterCommit/beforeCommit never gets called with `@Transactional` annotation and without it, it behaves fine until the delete is called on the repository.

Comment: It actually should trigger entity listeners - when your test method is finished, you listeners should run, as that's where transaction completion happens (try debugging this and see). Is delete called from test or tearDown?

Comment: I'm not suggesting to use transaction synchronization manager in entity listener, I'm suggesting to use it in test.

Comment: The delete is called from the test. I don't think having transaction synchronization manager in the test is viable solution for me. Maybe I did not explain very well what I am testing. On entity change beforeCommit/afterCommit stops specific services, and spins up the new ones based on the new data in the database. These services then execute actions and my tests are verifying that those actions are executed. So, I'm not verifying the actual data, I'm verifying that the correct actions are executed after the data in the database was changed.

Comment: Well, then syncmanager will likely be the wrong tool indeed. Are these services asynchronous? Is `remove` a part of one test or each test? In latter case, is it plausible for your test to wake `remove` in separate transaction to the test itself?

Comment: They are asynchronous. It's just part of one test currently. This behaves normally in exploratory (manual - non programatic) tests. At this point I'm just trying to figure out why adding `@Transactional` to method causes `@EntityListeners` not to be triggered. I can't find much information about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148431/discussion-between-m-prokhorov-and-srki-rakic).